# Is there a function in python to detect singular points on a curve?

Tags: python, sliding-window

I need to detect singular points (extremas, trend change, sharp changes) on a given curve plotted from a dataset. The first thing to come in mind is the inflexion point detection with derivation( but i dont have the mathematical expression of the plotted curve), second is how to detect angular points. so if possible can i build (using python) a sliding window which detects these kind of SP(singular points), if possible what are the libraries and function used ?

Thanks

[Singular point detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGBo0.png)

Comment: Wouldn’t it be simpler to determine these points from the dataset directly, instead of from a graphical representation?

Comment: There's very little information present here so far. Do you have access to the array of values that is plotted in the graph? Can you prepare a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Example?

Comment: Indeed it's easier to do it from the dataset (that i have access to) , i just wanted to verify if there is already an existing algorithm of this "sliding window".  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just [scraped some of your data](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/4d6ea10797050c6ea1423e652c5effc7/Default%20Dataset.csv) to show you that you can find points on the whole dataset, without using a sliding window (but you could, in theory):

1. Local extrema (find peaks in raw data)
2. Max Steepness (find peaks in 1st derivative)
3. Inflexion points (find peaks in 2nd derivative)

First, let's have a look on calculating the derivatives:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("Default Dataset.csv", 
                 sep=';', 
                 decimal=",", 
                 header=None)

### Interpolate linearily ###
x_new = np.linspace(0, df[0].iloc[-1], 2000)
y_new = np.interp(x_new, df[0], df[1])

### First and second derivative ###
diff1 = np.insert(np.diff(y_new), 0, 0)
diff2 = np.insert(np.diff(diff1), 0, 0)

### Plot everything ###
plt.figure(figsize=(12,3))
plt.subplot(131)
plt.plot(x_new, y_new)
plt.subplot(132)
plt.plot(x_new, diff1)
plt.subplot(133)
plt.plot(x_new, diff2)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Here, I also interpolate to have an equal spacing between the datapoints.
Further, I insert a `0` at position `0` using the `np.insert` function after the differentiation, to ensure the same shape as the raw data.

[image: Comparison of raw, 1st deriv and 2nd deriv]

Next, we will find the peaks:

```
import peakutils as pu

ix_abs   = pu.indexes(y_new, thres=0.5, min_dist=15)
ix_diff1 = pu.indexes(diff1, thres=0.5, min_dist=15)
ix_diff2 = pu.indexes(diff2, thres=0.5, min_dist=15)

plt.scatter(x_new[ix_abs], y_new[ix_abs], color='g', label='abs')
plt.scatter(x_new[ix_diff1], y_new[ix_diff1], color='r', label='first deriv')
plt.scatter(x_new[ix_diff2], y_new[ix_diff2], color='purple', label='second deriv')

plt.plot(x_new, y_new)
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

[image: peaks in data]

I am using the [peakutils](https://peakutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package, because it works nicely in almost all cases. You see that not all points that were indicated in your example were found. You can play around with different parameters for `threshold` and `minimum distance` to find a better solution. But this should be a good starting point for further research. Indeed, the `minimum distance` parameter would give you the desired **sliding window**.

Comment: Hi, Can you please let me know what this line in your code does, x_new = np.linspace(0, df[0].iloc[-1], 2000). What is x_new / y_new?.

Comment: The data was not spaced equally, so I interpolated them with equal spacing.